# Cannot test on a device after updating to iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I could test my application on my iPhone 4s device until yesterday.

After updating iOS to ver 6.1 this morning and trying to test my app on the same device, Xcode started complaining "No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

However, all the provisioning stuff seems fine :/

Has anyone experienced the same problem? Anyone knows how to get it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to update to the most recent version of XCode. Version 4.6 includes support for iOS 6.1 ([here's the changelog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012895-SW1)). According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#4.6), 4.6 went live on the 28th.

Comment: No problem. I had to deal with this today :)

Comment: I will accept your answer after 10 mins. It doesn't allow me to do so before that.